# How to determine if two variables are independent or dependent?

Tags: independence

If I have sample data but not the probabilities how can I find if my variables are dependent or independent?

Answer (score 0):

We do not often have access to the probabilities that generate a variable. We have access only to data attained through sampling. This means that there is some room for error. The observed conditional frequencies do not have to be exactly equal for the data to be independent: they need only be roughly equal. We can quantify what it means to be roughly equal, but, here, we’ll use a less rigorous, graphical approach.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]